# How to find out what filters were selected when inputting data

Tags: excel

I am working on a database and I am inputting data in new columns based on other data within the spreadsheet.

When inputting data into one of my columns I believe I accidentally had a filter (or combination of filters) selected meaning that a significant sample of qualifying data for input has been missed. However on rectifying this, the unknown filter actually produced significantly better results so I wondered if it was possible to work out what filters were enabled when I initially input my data?

I have a version of the spreadsheet with the initial entry (but all filters cleared) and a version of the spreadsheet which has been completed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This will create an array named currentFilterSettings where each element in the first dimension represents a column and the filter settings are saved in the second dimension.

You might want to run it with a break on the last available line and use the locals window to review the structure.

```
Sub GetCurrentFilterSettings()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currentFilterSettings()
    Dim i As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws.AutoFilter.Filters
    ReDim currentFilterSettings(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
        For i = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(i)
                If .On Then
                    currentFilterSettings(i, 1) = .Criteria1
                    If .Operator Then
                    currentFilterSettings(i, 2) = .Operator
                        If .Operator = xlAnd Or .Operator = xlOr Then
                            currentFilterSettings(i, 3) = .Criteria2
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```